# Populate Email To field using Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, outlook

I have a Python dictionary of 3 dataframes that have email addresses in them. I'd like to loop through the dataframes and populate the "mail.To" field in the below script. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Each Dataframe:

```
Date, ID, Email Address, Name
8/15, 02, test@test.com, Test
8/6, 05, test5@test.com, Test5
8/9, 02, test@test.com, Test
8/1, 05, test5@test.com, Test5
8/1, 04, test4@test.com, Test4

##Send email confirmation
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'POPULATED FROM DICT OF DATAFRAMES'
mail.Subject = 'Report'
mail.Body = """Report is attached."""
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post a minimal example of what such a dataframe might look like? Otherwise it is rather difficult to provide good solutions.

Comment: Hi Matt - I've edited the post. Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of googling I found that `mail.To` expects a string of semicolon separated emails, you can achieve this like this:

First, you turn the email column of the dataframe into a python list using the `.tolist()` method:

```py
>>> frame['email'].tolist()
>>> ['test@test.com','test5@test.com','test@test.com','test5@test.com','test4@test.com']
```

Then you join that list of email strings together with semicolons using the `.join()` method of the `;`  string:

```py
>>> '; '.join(frame['email'].tolist())
>>> 'test@test.com; test5@test.com; test@test.com; test5@test.com; test4@test.com'
```